# ActiveX Control in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, activex, ocx

i have a ActiveX Control in a windows project. i want to use that to my Web project. i read something about object,class id, codebase but it doesn't work. help me plz

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>WebForm1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="Form2" runat="server">
    <object id="DKroki" height="310" width="300" classid="bin/Interop.KrokiPrj.dll" viewastext>
    </object>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveX thing works only on IE.

Activating ActiveX Controls : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537508%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

**Update:**
You may benefit from [VisualJS](http://visualjs.net).NET in order to develop desktop like applications for browsers(touch compatible)